# Remove/disable PIN Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, pin

I have a PIN code on setup so I can quickly unlock my device. Its quick but not very secure so I would like to go back to a password, is this possible?

[image: PIN]

I couldn't find anything in the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the latest Windows 10 in November 2015 Ramhound's answer [(unlinking from a Microsoft account)](https://superuser.com/a/980131/140266) did not work for me. Perhaps because I created a PIN before linking my local account to a Microsoft account?

It turns out you have to "change" the PIN, but press **Cancel** instead of entering a new PIN. Here are the steps.

#### Click the *I forgot my PIN* link:

[image]

#### Enter your Windows password to verify your account:

[image]

#### Press the **Cancel** button instead:

[image]

#### The PIN is now removed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only method I have found that works with Windows 10 build 10240 and greater is to disconnect your account from your Microsoft Account.  In the process of doing this it disables you pin, since only accounts linked to a Microsoft Account, can be accessed with a pin.

Once you have completed the process to disconnect your Microsoft Account you can reconnect your Microsoft Account and after doing so only your Microsoft Account will work.

[image]

> 1. Go to settings from the start menu and then choose accounts.
> 2. On this page choose to sign in with a local account instead.
> 3. Provide your Microsoft account password and click on next.
> 4. On the next screen provide the details for your local account and just hit next.
> 5. It will then prepare your local account and your Microsoft account will be disconnected.

[An alternative method would have been to simply block the pin login from a group policy.](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-or-block-microsoft-accounts-in-windows-10/)

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Settings\AllowSignInOptions]
>   “value”=dword:00000000

[Image Source](http://www.gizmotimes.com/tips-tricks/windows-10/connect-disconnect-microsoft-account-windows-10/1902)